# Setting Struct Alias to null

Tags: c

I was studying some old code and noticed this:

```
struct node {
 ...
}*root=NULL;


int main()
{
...
root=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
...
}
```

I'm wondering if *root=NULL; can be just replaced with 'root;' or if there is any special advantage to having the alias root set to null.

Comment: Is `root` used *before* you `malloc()` it?

Comment: `*root = NULL;` : It will cause the error of "type is different".

Comment: Oh, I assumed you meant replacing `*root=NULL` with `*root`, my bad =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `root` is a pointer to a variable of type `struct Node`

```
struct node {
...
}*root=NULL;
```

This `root` is a variable of type `struct Node`

```
struct node {
...
}root ;
```

If you try to allocate using the second example the types do not match:

```
root=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Malloc returns a pointer, yet root is not a pointer.